# Strange django media deployment issue

Tags: django, cherokee, django-media

I managed to deploy cherokee as a reverse proxy for a django app running with cherrypy as information source.

All of the static files and media files seem to be served correctly except for a particular image.

On http://mydomain.com/media/files/none.png, I get a

```
The image "http://mydomain.com/media/files/none.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

But if I append a `?` behind that file's url, it shows up correctly as a 1x1 pixel image.

```
http://mydomain.com/media/files/none.png?
```

will give

```
none.png (PNG Image, 1 x 1 pixels)
```

which is expected and correct.

Why is this so?

Comment: Maybe you can provide output of curl for the following image? I'm assuming you're using some kind of linux + curl: `curl http://www.mydomain.com/media/files/none.png | hexdump -C` and `curl -I http://www.mydomain.com/media/files/none.png` with `?` and without to see the difference?

Comment: Sorry about wasting your time. It looks like it was simply a browser cache issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser cache problem. Issue solved a while back. Closing this.